# Which is more efficient Parallell.ForEach or Parallel.ForEachAsync in .NET 8.0 preview

Tags: c#, parallel.foreach, parallel.foreachasync

```
var tasks = new List<Task<TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie>>();

Parallel.ForEach(page, id =>
{
    var movieFromTmdb = _tmdbClient.GetMovieAsync(id);
    tasks.Add(movieFromTmdb);
});

await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

Or

```
var moviesBag = new ConcurrentBag<TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie>();
await Parallel.ForEachAsync(page,  async (movieId, token) =>
{
    var movieFromTmdb = await _tmdbClient.GetMovieAsync(movieId, token);

    moviesBag.Add(movieFromTmdb);
});
```

**Edit**
`_tmdbClient.GetMovieAsync` is a HTTP Rest call, I am doing pages of 200

Comment: What's even the point of using `Parallel.ForEach` here? Does `GetMovieAsync` do a lot of synchronous work before its I/O?

Comment: Also: what is significant about .NET 8 preview that you believe would make the answer different to a prior version of .NET with the same code?

Comment: What does the `_tmdbClient.GetMovieAsync` method do? Is it I/O-bound or CPU-bound? What is the return type of this method?

Comment: What do you mean by "efficient"? Are you aiming at efficient use of resources (i.e. do the work using the least amount of memory), or at maximizing the speed (doing the work as quickly as possible)? In the second case the correct term is performance, not efficiency.

Comment: edit the thread to say _tmdbClient.GetMovieAsync is a http rest call, doing pages of 200 each time

Comment: With `Parallel.ForEach` you're more likely doing 200 pages all at once.

Comment: I have set the limit to 100 concurrent connection max  `ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;`

I guess i was more asking which is better to write, the .`ForEach` or `ForEachAsync`

Comment: my `ForEach` loops are stacking 200 http calls each time, the `_tmdbClient` is a 3rd party library, anything above 200 in each loop results in ratelimiting by the 3rd party/themoviedb rest
there is a loop above the `ForEach` that processes 2M records but only doing 200 per loop to avoid rate limiting.  My question was more about if `ForEach` was better than `ForEachAsync` since the 3rd party is `async`

Comment: With the `Parallel.ForEach` you're _starting_ the requests in parallel. This will likely be faster than the requests themselves, so requests will be still running once the `ForEach` has moved onto another requst. Also `List` isn't thread-safe so you'd be losing tasks. As Theodor's answer says, `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is the correct way to do this.

Comment: I am aware that this already has an accepted answer, _but_ it seems to me it is somewhat XY. Wouldn't it make more sense to ask if the API has some sort of bulk endpoint to get the data from instead of using that huge amount of parallel connections requesting individual entities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Parallel.ForEachAsync` is the correct API to use. It's not a question of efficiency or performance. There is no comparison to do. The `Parallel.ForEach` is suitable for doing synchronous work only. Your work is asynchronous, so the `Parallel.ForEach` is unsuitable. For parallelizing asynchronous work, use the `Parallel.ForEachAsync`.